# Does Google's In App Purchase work on all markets?

Tags: android

I was wondering if Google's In App Purchase works on all markets. Not able to find much info on this online. Thanks for your help!

Comment: what do you mean By all Markets ?

Comment: like the Amazon market, getjar, etc.

Comment: what you mean by "does it work on amazon", do you mean are they using it?

Comment: can the app be deployed in the amazon market and if so, will its in-app purchase function work (if the in-app purchase uses google's apis)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. It depends on the Android Market application and related services. If the device doesn't have Market, IAB won't work. BTW, Amazon won't allow applications linking or invoking the Android Market. They have their own in-app billing solution, but it's currently in closed beta. You can try applying if you are already on the Amazon Appstore.

Comment: thanks nikolay. but say for getjar, it shouldn't be a problem as long as i have the google market app right?

Comment: Assuming they allow it, probably. You should probably be ready to handle the case when there is no Android Market, by using GetJar's API, etc.